# how to pass parameter from view to controller in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

In my controller I have this function:

```
$scope.add = function(key){
   $scope.key = key;
};
```

And this is my html view:

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="addVote({{key}});">Confirm</button>
```

My question is about the `ng-click="addVote({{key}})`. I want to call the `$scope.key` value in my view. It doesn't work. What the mistake I did?

Comment: It will be undefined in first call.

Comment: $scope.addVote must be their in your controller and addVote(key) is the correct syntax.

Comment: i want to do like this for couple of variables $scope.clearText = function(test){ $scope.test = ' ' ;}

Answer (score 2):

Remove  {{}} and send simple object

```
ng-click="addVote(key)"
```

Comment: is there any way to get the reference of that variable in the controller method ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform any interpolation in attributes such as ng-click. So your code should be as follows:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addVote(key);">Confirm</button>
```